# Git branch contains files from other branch

Tags: git, svn, version-control

Recently some project needs a specific feature A which I was working on in combination with another feature B right now separatly. Because this is quite a hassle with svn I decided to invest the time in setting my dev enviroment with git again.

I checked out svn with git-svn, created a branch "localconf", commited eclipse specifc changes, branched again and copied all changes from my former svn workspace in branch "feature-a-b". Now I did

```
git checkout localconf
git branch feature-a
```

to start a new branch "feature-a" beginning with localconf to incoparate those changes from "feature-a-b" I need.

But now localconf contains all files belonging to feature-a-b...  this rather puzzles me, aren't those former commits part of feature-a-b branch? git status / log does not indicate anything missing, to update ...

Googling something about git and branches turns up lot a too simple tutorials or lots of documentation not quite on the subject. How do I progress from here? Probably I'm missing something conceptionally...

**edit**:
After finding http://www.gitguys.com/topics/creating-and-playing-with-branches/  I've tried

```
git checkout master
```

and voila: those files from feature-a-b are not tracked.

```
git checkout localconf
```

restores them even if

```
git log --name-status
```

does not mention any of them ...

**edit2:**
Doh!

This has not been a branching/concept/whatever issue.: There has been a .gitignore file excluding all changes from feature-a-b in localconf...

Thanks all for their effort!

Comment: When you copied changes from svn into feature-a-b, did you `git add` everything and `git commit` before you checked out localconf?

Comment: Yes, I did. Logs of checked out branches are looking correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been a `.gitignore` file checked in both localconf and feature-a-b preventing any changes while switching branches ...

Answer (score 0):

`git branch branch_name` creates a new branch but doesn't switch to it.

`git checkout -b branch_name` creates a new branch and switches to it.

If you made changes following `git branch branch_name` and then committed, they will have been committed to the last branch you had checked out.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you were at commit `A` when you cloned the repository.

```
 - A
    \
     master - HEAD
```

Then you created and checked out branch `localconf`. A branch is a pointer to a commit. If you don't specify otherwise, it will point to the same place you currently are (`HEAD`).

```
 - A - localconf - HEAD
    \
     master
```

Then you committed commit `B` to that branch.

```
 - A - B - localconf - HEAD
    \
     master
```

`master` still points at `A`. `localconf` now points at `B`. Then you created another branch, `feature-a`. That branch, that pointer, points to the same place `HEAD` was at if you used a command like `git branch feature-a`. That's why you see the work you did on `localconf`.

```
 - A -      B - feature-a - HEAD
    \        \
     master   localconf
```

If you continue to work on `feature-a` from here and make commit `C`, you history looks like this.

```
 - A -      B - C - feature-a - HEAD
    \        \
     master   localconf
```

`master` points at `A`. `localconf` points at `B`. `feature-a` points at `C`.

If you've got commits on `feature-a` that you'd like to save, `git rebase --onto master localconf feature-a` will produce the following.

```
     C - feature-a - HEAD
    /
 - A -      B
    \        \
     master   localconf
```

If you haven't committed to `feature-a` yet, it may conceptually make more sense to delete and recreate the branch in the correct place.

Study the output of a command like `git log --decorate --graph --all --oneline` or use a gui like `gitk --all` frequently to understand what's going on as you branch and commit to your repository.

Comment: My history looks like graph four but actually it's called `feature-a-b` :). Now I want to return to `localconf` to start a new branch `feature-a` beginning from there : `git checkout localconf` but all files from checkin C are still there ... and not reported as untracked like when I am going back to `master`.